# EnqueuedTime not set from IotHub

Tags: uwp, .net-core, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have a stream analytics job being sourced from an IoTHub. I noticed that IoTHub properties are largely being set (ex: ConnectionDeviceId) but the **EnqueuedTime** is **NOT**. In some messages this property is missing altogether.
Here is an example of the relevant properties:

```
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-03-04T13:03:47.4294959Z",
    "PartitionId": 1,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-03-04T13:02:42.6930000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId": null,
        "CorrelationId": null,
        "ConnectionDeviceId": "Experiment1",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636146743722094236",
        "EnqueuedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
        "StreamId": null
```

Is there some configuration on the hub-side that I'm missing, to instruct the DeviceClient to set this property, prior to sending it to the IoTHub?

*I am specifically not using the EventEnqueuedUtcTime/EventProcessedUtcTime, because I'd like to set the timestamp of my stream job, to the time of the actual event on the Pi.*

I'm using a UWP app running on Windows IoT Core, on a Raspberry Pi.

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `EnqueuedTime` looks like staying the same. And it is a system property that you can't modify. Maybe you can [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues).

Or, you can try to utilize [application properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#message-format), define and add your own properties of ***the time of the actual event on the Pi***.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do both.